# inverse of the square matrix

Tags: matrices

It is given that AB is a square matrix and inverse exists. Then prove that inverse A and B inverse EXISTS. we cant really use reversal law as it use fact that A inverse and B inverse exists,..?

Comment: What is $B(AB)^{-1}$ relative to $A$?

Comment: I believe you assume that $A$ and $B$ are square too?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, $ Det(A)=0$ or $ Det(B)=0$. Then $ Det(AB)=Det(A)Det(B)=0$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $ A$ and $ B$ are both invertible.

If you would like to write the inverses, of $A$ and $B$, in terms of $ A, B$ and $ (AB)^{-1}$, use the fact that $ AB(AB)^{-1}=I$. Here, $ A^{-1}=B(AB)^{-1}$. Similarly you can find $ B$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** $\mathrm{rank}(AB)\leq\min\{\mathrm{rank}(A),\mathrm{rank}(B)\}$